# have different roles in different companies symfony 2.0

Tags: security, symfony, roles, fosuserbundle

I'm triying to develop an application which will contain different kinds of companies, and each company will have different roles.

This way, when a superadmin create a company, will define which roles can be attached to this kind of company.

For example, the superadmin could create a shopping center which could have a shop assistant and a director (each of them with different permissions); and another kind of companny which could be a coffee shop, which could have a waiter and a chef. 
Then, when an user loggin inside the application, and will want to create a new user, will only have the possibility of select the roles of his kind of company.

But I can't see the way to develop, using the security.yml file and the FOSUserBUndle.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

For this kind of purpose, I think you need to implement your security logic inside controllers ; with security.yml you can restrict some entire areas, but I don't think it will help in your case. Maybe you can first define some routes that would be accessible only to some roles (for example, "/waiter/*" for waiters)

Then you can implement like a new kind of roles ; each company can have a field "possible_roles" that will be an array of roles. For example, if a superadmin creates a coffee shop, then you will have `possible_roles = { "ROLE_WAITER", "ROLE_CHEF" }`

After that you just have to check if the user's role is in the company role's array, and if he has access to the page.

Is it clear ?